# Why my code won't do preorder form correctly in Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, binary-search-tree, preorder

I edited a code for a binary search tree, for strings. But there's a small problem. When I enter a simple input like A B C D E F, my program says the pre-order form is `A B C D E F`... which it should actually be `A B D E C F`.

> Since, it should print the word at the root then print the word at the left subtree in pre-order and then print the word at
>   the right subtree in pre-order.

Post order also should print `D E B F C A` but it prints `A B C D E F` and in-order should've printed `D B E A F C`... but it just gave me `F E D C B A`.

Any help is appreciated, I don't know what went wrong.

Here is the working full source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
string word;
Node* left;
Node* right;
public:
Node() { word=-1; left=NULL; right=NULL; };
void setWord(string aWord) { word = aWord; };
void setLeft(Node* aLeft) { left = aLeft; };
void setRight(Node* aRight) { right = aRight; };
string Word() { return word; };
Node* Left() { return left; };
Node* Right() { return right; };
};

class Tree {
 Node* root;
public:
 Tree();
 ~Tree();
 Node* Root() { return root; };
 void addNode(string word);
 void inOrder(Node* n);
 void preOrder(Node* n);
 void postOrder(Node* n);
private:
 void addNode(string word, Node* leaf);
 void freeNode(Node* leaf);
};

Tree::Tree() {
 root = NULL;
}

Tree::~Tree() {
 freeNode(root);
}

void Tree::freeNode(Node* leaf)
{
if ( leaf != NULL )
{
   freeNode(leaf->Left());
   freeNode(leaf->Right());
   delete leaf;
}
}

void Tree::addNode(string word) {
 if ( root == NULL ) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    n->setWord(word);
    root = n;
 }
 else {
   addNode(word, root);
 }
 }

void Tree::addNode(string word, Node* leaf) {
if ( word <= leaf->Word() ) {
   if ( leaf->Left() != NULL )
      addNode(word, leaf->Left());
   else {
      Node* n = new Node();
      n->setWord(word);
      leaf->setLeft(n);
   }
}
else {
   if ( leaf->Right() != NULL )
      addNode(word, leaf->Right());
   else {
      Node* n = new Node();
      n->setWord(word);
      leaf->setRight(n);
   }
}
}

void Tree::inOrder(Node* n) {
if ( n ) {
   inOrder(n->Left());
   cout << n->Word() << " ";
   inOrder(n->Right());
}
}

void Tree::preOrder(Node* n) {
if ( n ) {
   cout << n->Word() << " ";
   preOrder(n->Left());
   preOrder(n->Right());
}
}


void Tree::postOrder(Node* n) {
if ( n ) {
   postOrder(n->Left());
   postOrder(n->Right());
   cout << n->Word() << " ";
}
}

int main() {
string word;
Tree* tree = new Tree();
while(word != "end"){
   cin >> word;
   if(word == "end"){
       break;
   }
   tree->addNode(word);
}

cout << "In order traversal" << endl;
tree->inOrder(tree->Root());
cout << endl;

cout << "Pre order traversal" << endl;
tree->preOrder(tree->Root());
cout << endl;

cout << "Post order traversal" << endl;
tree->postOrder(tree->Root());
cout << endl;

delete tree;
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to execute each statement, one at a time, and *watch* values of variables.  Edit your post with details about the suspect statement, after you use the debugger.

Comment: Hi @ThomasMatthews I'm quite unsure about how to use a debugger. Is there any native way to debug in Visual Studio C++ Express edition? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test example `A B C D E F` your tree is basically a linked list. First, you insert `A`, so it becomes your new root. `B` is bigger than `A`, so when you insert it, it goes as a right child. The same happens for all next strings:

`A`->`B`->`C`->`D`->`E`->`F`.

So when you traverse your tree from left, you just print your list as it is since there are no left child in any of the nodes in the tree. When you traverse it from the right, you just print it backwards.

Since your tree is unbalanced, this is an expected behaviour. There are no bugs in your code from what I can see. Try to add balancing or make another root.

Comment: How do I make a tree without sorting then? Because when I try all I get as output is weird things, like `A` or `A F F`. Doesn't work properly.

Comment: It is a tree. Even a linked list is technically a tree. If you ask how to make a *balanced* tree (tree with max height of log(n)), then you have to implement balancing for your tree (google it). I don't understand what you mean by 'make a tree without sorting'? You already implemented a working binary search tree. If you just want a tree that is always log(n) height, take a look at "heap (data structure)", but heap tree is not a binary search tree.

Comment: I meant, if I want to create a tree like that: https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F991%2F99188ce0-2ecc-478e-93b3-ada532011ac0%2Fphpstal8r.png

What should I do? Without making B go to the right, C to the right, D to the right etc... All should just appear like the one in the image. I fail to do that.

Comment: Either balance your tree (hard way), or just change your `add` method: use *breadth first traversal* instead of *depth first traversal* and insert new node at first empty space you find.